# Bernoulli's Principle Versus Reynold Transport Theorem - Flow Hitting Flat Plate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I have been running into an issue regarding the analysis of the forces involved when a vertical flow is hitting a fixed horizontal flat plate. Consider the below scenarios:

Scenario 1:

Consider a horizontal plate that is fixed in space subject to a flow moving in a direction normal to the plate. My first thought here to find the rough force acting on the plate was to use Bernoulli's equation and consider the flow hitting the plate to stagnate such that all of the dynamic pressure of the flow interfacing the plate turns into static pressure:
$$ P_1 + \frac 1 2 \rho v^2_1 + \rho g h_1 = P_2 + \frac 1 2 \rho v^2_2 + \rho g h_2 $$
Where we can neglect gravity, and assume atmospheric pressure starting in the flow, and full stagnation when the flow hits the plate:

$$\rho g \left( h_2 - h_1 \right) \approx 0$$
$$P_1 = 0$$
$$v_2 = 0$$

Such that:
$$\frac 1 2 \rho v^2_1 = P_2$$
(where $P_2$ is the pressure directly at the plate, and $v_1$ is the velocity of the flow that the plate is subject to)

Now to find the force acting on the plate, I would take this pressure and multiply it by the area of the plate:

$$ F = \frac {\rho v^2_1 A} {2} $$

Scenario 2:

Ok, now consider a similar plate, fixed in the same position, but now there is a jet of fluid hitting it that is travelling in the direction normal to the plate, then upon hitting the plate, direction changes where half of the jet splits one way, and the other half goes the other way. To tackle this problem, I applied Reynolds Transport Theorem:

$$\frac{DB_{sys}}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{CV}\rho bd V +\int_{CS}\rho b \vec{V}\cdot \vec{n}dA$$

Given that the flow is in a steady state, the accumulation term here goes to 0, and solving the integral gets us the equation in the following simplified form:

$$\sum F = \sum_{Outlets} \vec V_o \dot m_o - \sum_{Inlets} \vec V_i \dot m_i$$

Now, only looking at the forces in the y-direction (along the initial flow direction of the fluid jet), there is no outlet flow in this direction so we are just left with:

$$F = -\vec V_i \dot m_i$$

Being the force required to change the momentum of the fluid. Flipping the sign here to be the equal and opposite force on the plate, and subbing in $V_i = \frac {\dot m_i} {A_i \rho}$:

$$F = \frac {\dot m^2} {A \rho}$$

where $\dot m$ is the mass flow rate of the jet, and $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the jet.

Ok, so now comes the part that has been confusing me; comparing scenarios 1 and 2. To make the equations more comparable, I applied $v = \frac {\dot m} {A \rho}$ to the final force equation in scenario 1. The $A$ here would still be the area of the plate, and would also be the area of the flow that interacts with the plate (I think this can be used as an equivalent, but I'm not completely sure here). This gives us:

$$F = \frac {\rho A} {2} \left( \frac {\dot m} {A \rho} \right)^2$$
$$F = \frac {\dot m^2} {2 A \rho}$$

Now for argument's sake, lets say that the area of the plate in scenario 1 is equal to the area of the fluid jet in scenario 2. Now I am left with 2 very similar analyses of flow hitting a plate directly onward, but the final force equations differ by a factor of 2. I would have thought that these would be much more similar. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Just to make sure before providing an answer; in Scenario 1 the flow literally comes to a halt (i.e. there is no outflow anywhere) when hitting the plate, whereas in the second one it deflects symmetrically off the sides?

Comment: @aghostinthefigures Yes - I'm not sure if I'm able to do this? I have seen Bernoulli's equation used like this this before for pitot tube analyses and rough wind force calculations - but I am not very experienced in the field of fluid mechanics. Let me know if you think that this does not make sense.